# Checking for win on a wrap-around Connect 6 board

Tags: java, homework, connect-four

I have a method, that checks win conditions on a "Torus" board, which is a board without any borders.  This means that if you place 4 diagonal stones on the top left, and 2 diagonal stones in the bottom right, if they are in the same diagonal and would connect if you ignored the border, which then would lead to a win. Basically it's a Connect 6 Game.

`size()` returns the size of the board which either is 18 or 20.

`currentPlayer` is a String like : "P1" or "P2".

`r` and `c` are the row and column where a move has just been made.

```
public boolean checkTorusWinner(int r, int c){ 

    int count = 0;
    boolean hasWinner = false;
    String currentPlayer = board[r][c];
    int hSize = size();
    int vSize = size();

    /*
    Checks Horizontally for a Win.
     */
    for (int i = c; i < hSize; i++) {
        if (board[r][i] == currentPlayer) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
        if (i == size() - 1) {
            hSize = size() - 2;
            for (int j = 0; j < hSize; j++) {
                if (board[r][j] == currentPlayer) {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    count = 0;
                }
                if (count == 6) {

                    boardType = "none";
                    hasWinner = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == 6) {
            boardType = "none";
            hasWinner = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    /*
    Checks Vertically for a Win
     */
    for (int i = r; i < vSize; i++) {
        if (board[i][c] == currentPlayer) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
        if (i == size() - 1) {
            i = -1;
            vSize = size() - 2;
        }
        if (count == 6) {

            boardType = "none";
            hasWinner = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    /*
    Checks Diagonally from Top left to Bottom right
     */
    if (c - r >= 0) {
        int startingC;
        startingC = c - r;
        int size = size();
        for (int i = r, j = c; j < size; i++, j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == currentPlayer) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
            if (j == size() - 1) {
                j = startingC - 1;
                i = -1;
                size = size() - 2;

            }
            if (count == 6) {
                boardType = "none";
                hasWinner = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        int size = size();
        int startingR;
        startingR = r - c;
        for (int i = r, j = c; i < size; i++, j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == currentPlayer) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
            if (i == size() - 1) {
                j = -1;
                i = startingR - 1;
                size = size() - 2;

            }

            if (count == 6) {
                boardType = "none";
                hasWinner = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    /*
    Checks Diagonally from bottom left to top right;
     */
    if (r + c <= 17) {
        int loop = 0;
        int startingR;
        startingR = r + c;
        for (int i = r, j = c; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == currentPlayer) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }

            if (i == 0 && loop == 0) {
                i = startingR + 1;
                j = -1;
                loop++;
            }

            if (count == 6) {
                boardType = "none";
                hasWinner = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    } else if (r + c > 17) {
        int loop = 0;
        int startingC;
        startingC = (r + c) - (size() - 1);
        for (int i = r, j = c; i >= startingC; i--, j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == currentPlayer) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
            if (i == startingC && loop == 0) {
                i = size();
                j = startingC - 1;
                loop++;
            }
            if (count == 6) {
                boardType = "none";
                hasWinner = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return hasWinner;
}
```

Unfortunately this method's length doesn't meet the requirement for my university: it has to be a maximum of 80 lines. I don't know how I'm supposed to shorten this code so that it still works.

Comment: for the record... are you mandated to solve the problem in a single method?

Comment: I think it is shorter to write a method that ignores which was the last move and just loops the entire board to find any winning combination, and if so, by which player.

Comment: This doesn't look like it returns the correct result.  Have you checked it?  In particular, what happens if the newest piece is in the middle of a horizontal sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing your code.

---

Your code is a *procedural* approach to the problem.

There is nothing wrong with procedural approaches in general, but Java is an *object oriented* (OO) programming language and if you want to become a good *Java* programmer then you should start solving problems in an OO way.

But OOP doesn't mean to "split up" code into random classes.

The ultimate goal of OOP is to reduce code duplication, improve readability and support reuse as well as extending the code.

Doing OOP means that you follow certain principles which are (among others):

- information hiding / encapsulation
- single responsibility
- separation of concerns
- KISS (Keep it simple (and) stupid.)
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself.)
- "Tell! Don't ask."
- Law of demeter ("Don't talk to strangers!")

### How might that help to improve your code?

From an OO point of view you have the current position and you have to check if that position is part of a line of at least 5 other (excluding itself) equal elements.

The first implication is that you only have to look at the current positions neighbors and that there is no need to scan the whole board.

The easieast way is to go in each direction and count the consecutive neighbors belonging to the current player. Afterwards you add the opposit directions and check the sum.

I use a trick to safely calculate an index in "wrap around" arrays:

```
(arrayLength + currentIndex + differece) % arrayLength
```

where `%` is the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator.

Here is how I would implement that:

```
  class FiledPosition{
    final int r, c;
    FiledPosition(int r, int c){
        this.r=r;
        this.c=c;
    }
  }
  interface NeighborCalculator
    FiledPosition getFor(FiledPosition current);
  }

  enum Direction {NORTH,NORTH_EAST,EAST,SOUTH_EAST,SOUTH,SOUTH_WEST,WEST,NORTH_WEST}
```

the code above may live in separate classes. What follows must be in your solution class

```
  private final Direction[][] opposits = new Direction[][]{
    {NORTH,SOUTH},    
    {NORTH_EAST,SOUTH_WEST},
    {NORTH_WEST,SOUTH_EAST},
    {EAST,WEST}
  }

  private final int WIN_COUNT_EXCLUDUNG_CURRENT = 5;
  Map<Direction, NeighborCalculator> neigborSelector = new HashMap<>();

public boolean checkTorusWinner(int r, int c){   

  neigborSelector.put(NORTH, new NeighborCalculator(){ // pre java8 anonymous inner class
       public  FiledPosition getFor(FiledPosition currentPoint ){
          return new Point((vSize+currentPoint.r-1)%vSize, currentPoint.c));
       }
  });
  neigborSelector.put(NORTH_EAST,currentPoint -> new Point((vSize+currentPoint.r-1)%vSize, (hSize+currentPoint.c+1)%hSize));  // java8 lambda
  neigborSelector.put(EAST,currentPoint -> new Point(currentPoint.r, (hSize+currentPoint.c+1)%hSize));
  neigborSelector.put(SOUTH_EAST,currentPoint -> new Point((vSize+currentPoint.r+1)%vSize, (hSize+currentPoint.c+1)%hSize)); 
  // similar for all directions, should be in the classes constructor.

  Map<Direction, Counter> lineSectionCounts = new HashMap<>();
  String currentPlayer = board[r][c];
  int hSize = size();
  int vSize = size();

  // count consecutive same in each direction without current
  for(Direction direction : Direction.values()){
     int consecutiveSame = 0;
     FiledPosition neigborPosition = neigborSelector.get(direction).getFor(new FiledPosition(r,c));
     while(currentPlayer.equals(board[neigborPosition.r][neigborPosition.c])){
        consecutiveSame++;
        neigborPosition = neigborSelector.get(direction).getFor(neigborPosition);
      }         
      lineSectionCounts.put(consecutiveSame); // auto boxed
   }

  // sum up opposit directions
  for(Direction[] opposit : opposits){
    if(WIN_COUNT_EXCLUDUNG_CURRENT < lineSectionCounts.get(oposit[0]) + lineSectionCounts.get(oposit[1])) // auto unbox
         return true; // current Player won.
  }
  return false; // no winner yet
}
```

This complete code has 57 lines (24 without the configuration). There are 4 lines missing to completly configure `neigborSelector` map (if you use jav8 lambdas).

This code uses basic Java concepts like *classes*, *interfaces*  and *enums* you should already have heared of.

Comment: This solution has 8 repetitions of code where the only difference is the -1, 0, +1. Additionally, since SOUTH is basically "NEGATIVE NORTH", defining SOUTH is effectively duplication of NORTH. I think it would be more DRY to have the four "real" directions (horizontal, vertical, diagonal forward, diagonal backward) as small objects only containing the "x-delta" and "y-delta" ({1,0}, {0,1}, {1,1}, {1,-1}). Then the code (or a method on the direction class) can just negate both values to get the opposite direction where needed.

Comment: Additionally, WIN_COUNT_EXCLUDUNG_CURRENT is very specific, a WIN_COUNT (and taking -1 if "current" needs to be excluded) would be far more reusable and readable.

Comment: @JanErikGunnar *"WIN_COUNT_EXCLUDUNG_CURRENT is very specific, a WIN_COUNT (and taking -1 if "current" needs to be excluded) would be far more reusable and readable"* `WIN_COUNT_EXCLUDUNG_CURRENT` is an *implementation detail* but in OOP we reuse *behavior*, not *code*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you explain in which way WIN_COUNT_EXCLUDUNG_CURRENT = 5 is a better constant than WIN_COUNT = 6?

Comment: @JanErikGunnar it exactly explains *my* intention when programming the logic. Nobody else is expected to "reuse" it. If I'd go with `6` my logic woul need to initialize the counter with `1` instead of `0`which yould need an extra explanation *and* I had to compare for `6<sum` which is even more odd...

Comment: Fair enough, although I disagree :)

Comment: It's a big world with room for more than one way to look at it... ;o)

Comment: "If I'd go with 6 my logic woul need to initialize the counter with 1 instead of 0which yould need an extra explanation and I had to compare for 6<sum which is even more odd..." -- no? If you had WIN_COUNT = 6, you would just replace your only use of  WIN_COUNT_EXCLUDUNG_CURRENT with either "(WIN_COUNT - 1)", or add + 1 to the other side of the comparison.

Comment: *"you would just replace your only use of `WIN_COUNT_EXCLUDUNG_CURRENT` with either "`(WIN_COUNT - 1)`", or add `+ 1` to the other side of the comparison."* which is an additional operation an thus higher complexity with the (small) potential for more errors. Still I had to explay `+1` or `-1`...

Comment: On the other hand, the number of operations you are doing are the same, you have just done one of them in your head and hardcoded the result, which is more difficult to debug :)

Comment: @JanErikGunnar it is still part of my algorithm *not* to count the current position and the constant name reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- obviously, break into smaller methods if allowed
- There are many magic numbers and strings. 17? 6? "none"? Put them in variables or constants to make the code more readable and easier to adjust.
- you are changing hSize value within a loop where hSize is the bound of the loop. This is very error prone!
- hasWinner = true; break; can be replaced by return true;
- modulo operator is fantastic for "looping" arrays. Example:
  length = 18;
  position = 17;
  array[(position) % length] == array[(position+1) % length]
  This will compare position 17 with position 0.
- code can probably be simplified and more generic by taking less regard to the position of the last move.
- the method sets board type to "none". I assume this resets the board. This makes the name of the method (checkTorusWinner) missleading
- pseudo code for very easy approach

```
For each x:
    For each y:
        Set xwin = ywin = diagFwdWin = diagBackwdWin = true. 
        For each n = 1... winLength-1:
            If board [x] [y] != board [(x+n) % boardwidth] [y] then
                Xwin =false
            End if
            // Same if,  but instead, y+n % boardheight, Ywin
            // same if,  but both x+n AND y+n, diagbackwdWin
            // same if,  but both x+n and y MINUS n, diagfwdWin
        End for
        If Xwin or ywin or diagFwdWin or diagBackwdWin == true then
            Return true
        End if
    End for
End for
Return false
```

For better performance, x and y in outer loop can be limited to position of last added +/- winLength